# How can I prevent Orgmode from opening links to `*.jot` files using GNU `less`

Tags: org-mode, org-link

When I open a link in Emacs Orgmode to a `*.txt` or `*.org` file, the files are opened in a new Emacs buffer.  However, I have a self-created set of plain-text `*.jot` files.  If I open an otherwise identical link to such a file (e.g. by renaming `file.txt` to `file.jot` and updating the link), emacs "opens" it with GNU `less`, which means nothing happens.

I cannot find any mention of `jot` or `less` in my emacs `init.el` or KDE/Plasma file associations (I just assigned `*.jot` to Emacs in my System settings, even though `xdg-open file.jot` already opened it with Emacs).  When I try this with `emacs -q`, I still get the same result.

Is there anything special about `*.jot` files for emacs, should I add an Emacs setting to force the desired behaviour, or should I be looking elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(push '("\\.jot\\'" . emacs) org-file-apps)
```

Org sometimes looks in odd system places (mailcap?) for file associations.